# Who are the other members of the Slug Club in Slughorn's photos?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification

The photos below were released on the now defunct [www.theroadtohogwarts.com](http://www.theroadtohogwarts.com/intl/es/game.html) website.

It seems likely that these were taken at much the same time as the principal filming for Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince with the topmost being a slightly enlarged (and static) version the one that Slughorn shows Harry at the start of HBP when talking about Lily Potter. Another image has a student that is clearly intended to be a younger Lucius Malfoy, with his trademark long white hair and Slytherin robes.

**Can we positively identify who any of the other students seen below are supposed to be?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is the long-haired man in Lily's picture *might* be a young Sirius Black. But I don't there's enough evidence to positively identify anyone but Lucius and Lily.

Comment: @TenthJustice - The woman rightmost in the [fifth picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqWhF.png) looks a lot like Delores Umbridge (Imelda Staunton)

Comment: There are some lists of member names throughout the book if I remember correctly. One could guess based on that.

Comment: Unnamed extras?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Very possibly.

Comment: @CBredlow - Check out that 'fro. Magnificent.

Comment: It looks like the other students in the picture with Lucius, and all the female students (and possibly the male ones as well from their ties) are all Slytherins. I’m not sure who they’re actually supposed to be though, if any of them are anyone specific.

Comment: @Valorum That could be [Dominik Feri](https://www.google.cz/search?q=dominik+feri&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=3ylQ6DGNMKWP6M%253A%252CB-Yf-LTPtG4ZvM%252C_&usg=__0DyVFJxjI7t9gkNwT0oUJ6bHsTY%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR0aC93PPaAhXGDewKHY2qCswQ_h0IqQEwCw#imgrc=3ylQ6DGNMKWP6M:), Czech parliamentarian ;).

Comment: @TenthJustice Perhaps Regulus Black then? I doubt Sirius would have wanted anything to do with a Club. But Slughorn would have definitely wanted a Black in his group.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I could shed a little light as I am actually in one of these photos. I was an extra in the 1940's Slug Club photo (the second from bottom one with the three boys on the sofa and the girls behind either side of Slughorn). Our costumes all have Slug Club (1940s) labels although we were not told exactly what year it was, however, we were organised so "young McGonagall" was standing next Slughorn, this was the girl with dark hair.

[image]

Comment: That's extremely interesting as it implies that each picture has one supposedly recognisable character (Lily, Lucius, McGonagall, etc )

Comment: Which could well make the middle picture Bellatrix(?), Lestrange(?) and Voldemort(?)

Answer (score 2):

**We don't know...**

The [assumed past members](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/slug-club/) of the Slug Club are;

> - Lily Evans
> - Dirk Cresswell (now Head of the Goblin Liaison Office)
> - Barnabas Cuffe (now editor of the Daily Prophet) (HBP4)
> - Ambrosius Flume (now owner of Honeydukes) (HBP4)
> - Ciceron Harkiss (HBP4)
> - Gwenog Jones (now Captain of the Holyhead Harpies) (HBP4)
> - Marcus Belby's Uncle Damocles (inventor of the Wolfsbane potion) (HBP7)
> - Cormac McLaggen's Uncle Tiberius (HBP7)
> - Lucius Malfoy (HBP7)
> - Theodore Nott's father (HBP7)
> - Eldred Worple (author of Blood Brothers: My Life Amongst the Vampires) (HBP15)
> - Tom Riddle

Only a list of 12, and there are 38 students shown in the photos. We could assume that each of those members are represented in the photos but we do not really know their age nor their physical attributes beyond a select few (i.e. Lily, Lucius, and Tom). Couple this with only being able to guess what decade the photos were taken in  based on Slughorn's age (kinda hard to tell) and the clothing styles if we don't have a known member again (Lily and Lucius; Tom doesn't seem to be in a picture).

Even the [HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Slug_Club) (which has been known to the members of this community to be unreliable) does not even take a guess at who is in the photos. Captions are just generic descriptions like

> "Slughorn and a band of former club-members, inlcuding Lily Evans."
>
> "Slughorn with four girls and three boys, likely between 1930 and 1950."

So without a direct identification from cast or crew of the films I don't think we have enough information to go on.

Answer (score -1):

My friends and I were looking at Voldemort supporters and stumbled upon Alecto Carrow in our research today. Upon looking at the pictures one of my friends pointed out how a girl in the sixth picture bottom right seems to have an uncanny resemblance to Alecto Carrow. She looks alot like  the Death Eater especially if you pay attention to the face and it's bone structure.[image: Alecto Carrow][image: Alecto Carrow in the Slug club]

Comment: This is a question and answer site not a discussion forum and so answers should be answers to the question. This is one but I have removed the discussion side of things with _"What do you guys think?"_ The answer could also be improved if you [edit]ed in a picture of Alecto and the girl you are saying she looks like.